# Choropleth in Python not showing different shade

Tags: python, matplotlib, choropleth

I am trying to create a choropleth with shades showing prices but when I created choropleth, it doesn't really show the data but instead it shaded every area with the same color.
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OepTV.png)

[Choropleth map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWsdL.png)

Comment: Just to be sure, the data type in the price column is numeric, right? If it is numeric, what happens if you reduce the number of digits?

Comment: I changed all of them to integer already but it still dont work

Comment: Can't I make it an integer type? After that, as `maneged.columns`, does 'Price' contain any extra spaces? If it's still correct, submit your data and code.